# Is it possible to turn a Jhipster application into a mobile app?

Tags: java, html, jhipster

Is it possible to turn a Jhipster application into a mobile app? Like an app with HTML5 through Phonegap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible but it means substantial manual effort to split the server side from the client side, put the client side into a Cordova project, adapt the build process.
You will also have to add CORS headers on server-side probably as a servlet filter and also on client-side.

Of course this assumes that you decide to keep Bootstrap as your CSS framework, if you decide to use a mobile framework like Ionic, you will have to rewrite all your views and some parts of your controllers too.

So it's feasible especially if you are already an experienced angular developer.

Another possibility would be to write another yeoman generator that reads JHipster json format describing entities to generate ionic code.